# Is there a way to speed up vanity address generation with GPU / Cuda / Mojo?

Tags: wallets, web3.py, python

Currently using Python to generate a vanity address with basically this notebook - https://github.com/wolovim/ethereum-notebooks/blob/master/Address%20Mining.ipynb

Anyone know how to incorporate the GPU or ML to speed it up ?